# show json data in table form without using html in asmx web service

Tags: asp.net, asmx

I have a list of class Employee `List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();` i am getting data from database and adding that data into list `employees.Add(employee);` while employee is an object of class Employee. Then serializing this list to `Json` using this

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
js.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
return js.Serialize(employees);
```

and it is being printed in this format
[{"code":0,"name":alies},{"code":1,"name":trish}] but i want this data in table format. Please help